# SQL Error When Making New Products on Magento "Column 'price_type' cannot be null"

Tags: magento-1.9, products, sql

[image]

This is the error I am getting. This error message shows whether I am duplicating a product or if I am making a new one. I'm unsure of what is causing this, but the log clearly shows it trying to write a "NULL" column.

This is for a client of mine who hasn't tried to add a new product since he's been with me (only 3 months, so not long). So I am unsure of what backup we would need to restore, and I've put in a ton of work that I'd like to not have to re-implement.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error showing is saying that price_type is getting **no** value. At the same time is telling you that price_type cannot and may never be **null**

You could try and check all the values send from the form and locate the problem there.

You can check here what price_types are: http://magetips.com/price-types-in-magento-and-how-the-price-rules-work.html/

I assume the form you're submitting does not contain a value regarding price_type so you should add this to the form.

Hope this helps

Comment: So you are saying I need to add a field in the product creation form that assigns a value to 'price_type'.

Can this be done through the Attribute Set?

Comment: You could add an extra hidden field with the desired price_type, or you could add this data at the moment of running the script causing this error.